# ASP.net validator issue with onchange event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am working on the employment history of a web based application that I am developing.  What is supposed to happen:

If user enters the company name of a second company, certain other fields for the second company become required.  If the second companies name is left blank the other field validators are to remain disabled.

For the most part this is working without any issues; however, when someone enters something in second companies name box, and clicks next, it activates the validators.  If this is not correct and they remove whatever it was that was typed in the second companies name box, the validators are not being disabled again.

I am using an onchange event in the textbox that calls a javascript function to enable and disable the validators and I am unsure why it is not working.

Here is my text box that is being validated against.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany2" runat="server" onchange="validateCompany3()" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCompany2" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtCompany2"
            errormessage="Please indicate which company you worked for."
            Enabled="false"
            ForeColor="Red"
            Text="*">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function validateCompany2(source, args) {
    var company = document.getElementById("<%=txtCompany2.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2 = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2City = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2City.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2State = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2State.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Phone = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2Phone.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Supervisor = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2Supervisor.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Start = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2StartDate.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2End = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2EndDate.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Job = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2JobTitle.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2StartSal = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2StartingSalary.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2EndSal = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2EndingSalary.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Resp = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2Responsibilities.ClientID %>");
    var valCompany2Reason = document.getElementById("<%=rfvCompany2ReasonForLeaving.ClientID %>");

    if (company == "" || company == null || company.value == null)
    {
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2City, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2State, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Phone, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Supervisor, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Start, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2End, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Job, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2StartSal, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2EndSal, false); 
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Resp, false);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Reason, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2City, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2State, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Phone, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Supervisor, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Start, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2End, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Job, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2StartSal, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2EndSal, true); 
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Resp, true);
        ValidatorEnable(valCompany2Reason, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your onchange says validateCompany3 but the code you posted is validateCompany2.  Typo?

Comment: I accidently copied the text box from company three here.  I corrected it.   Thanks,

Comment: Can you post this method, ValidatorEnable()?  Did you try to add an alert to it to make sure it is being called?  Also check the console and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I didn't think about adding alerts to verify.  Using alerts I managed to track down where the issue was.  I changed each location that had "company" to "company.value" and it now works.